# Discord.JS v13 set nickname to bot Missing Permissions

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to change bot's username with  `await client.guilds.cache.get(msg.guild.id).me.setNickname("something")`, but it returns Missing Permissions error. The bot has even administrator permissions in the server and I can't figure out what's the problem. Is it Intents error or idk?

```
DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/tom/Documents/Phyc/Phyc/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:349:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/tom/Documents/Phyc/Phyc/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async GuildMemberManager.edit (/home/tom/Documents/Phyc/Phyc/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberManager.js:277:15)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (/home/tom/Documents/Phyc/Phyc/bot.js:1678:9) {
  method: 'patch',
  path: '/guilds/919217411268411392/members/872813046236606505',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: {
    json: { nick: 'something', communication_disabled_until: undefined },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent.

Comment: I already have GUILD_MEMBERS intent.

Answer (score 1):

`DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`

at some point. This error can be caused by one of the following reasons:

• Your bot is missing the needed permission to execute this action in it’s calculated base or final permissions (requirement changes based on the type of action you are trying to execute).

• You provided an invalid permission number while trying to create overwrites. (The calculator on the apps page returns decimal values while the developer documentation lists the flags in hex. Make sure you are not mixing the two and don’t use the hex prefix 0x where not applicable)

• It is trying to execute an action on a guild member with a role higher than or equal to your bots highest role.

• It is trying to modify or assign a role that is higher than or equal to its highest role.

• It is trying to execute a forbidden action on the server owner.

• It is trying to execute an action based on another unfulfilled factor (for example reserved for partnered guilds).

• It is trying to execute an action on a voice channel without the VIEW_CHANNEL permission.

**Good Luck**